# Can ashes be stored in house?

Tags: scripture, death

I was told that if one is unable to disperse ashes in river immediately then the same needs to be hung from tree. But should not be stored in house.

Are there any scriptural references on what should one do if immediate dispersion of ashes is not possible ? And for how long can one store the ashes ?